# Javascript асинхронная загрузка php

Tags: php, javascript

До этого использовал функцию `load` для того что бы загрузить `php` файл в `html`, все работало хорошо. В этот же раз содержимое `php` загружается только после того, как я проведу мышкой по странице, либо нажму клавишу. А хотелось бы что бы грузилось сразу без дополнительных действий. Собственно вот страница `html` со скриптом, если к слову его перенести на самый верх, то содержимое вовсе не грузится:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta name="description" 
              content="Tracking the progress of players, forecasting matches.">
        <meta name="author" 
              content="The community of sport analysts and experts.">
        <meta name="keywords" 
              content ="soccer, tracking, forecasting, result, player, progress, match">

        <title>Tracking &amp; Forecasting</title>



        <link href="../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function() { $("#newsadmin").load('index.php'); }); </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NiceLogo</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                                Login</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="news">

                <div id="newsadmin"></div>

        </div>

        <footer class="container">test</footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Это php, который надо отобразить - сам по себе он отображается сразу:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Новости</title>
</head>
<?php
  // Выставляем уровень обработки ошибок (http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=23)
  Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 

  // Этот файл выводит первые $pnumber новостей
  // Устанавлинваем соединение с базой данных
  require_once("config.php");
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<?php
  // Выясняем общее количество новостей в базе данных, для того чтобы
  // правильно отображать ссылки на последующие новости.
  $tot = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM news WHERE hide='show' AND putdate <= NOW()");
  if ($tot)
  {
    $total = mysql_result($tot,0);
    // Если в базе новостей меньше чем $pnumber
    // выводим их без вывода ссылки "Все новости".
    if($pnumber < $total) echo "<p class='linkblock'><a href=news.php class='linkblock'>Все новости</a>";
  }
  else puterror("Ошибка при обращении к блоку новостей");
  // Запрашиваем все видимые новости, т.е. те, у которых в базе данных hide='show',
  // если это поле будет равно 'hide', новость не будет отображаться на странице
  $query = "SELECT * FROM news 
            WHERE hide='show' AND putdate <= NOW()
            ORDER BY putdate DESC
            LIMIT $pnumber";
  $new = mysql_query($query);
  if(!$new) puterror("Ошибка при обращении к блоку новостей");

  if(mysql_num_rows($new) > 0)
  {
    while($news = mysql_fetch_array($new))
    {
      ?>
      <div id="block">
      <div class = "jumbotron">
      <?
      // Выводим заголовок новости
      echo "<p class=newsblockzag><h4>".$news['name']."</h4></p>";
      // Формируем анонс
      // Переменная $numchar содержит примерное
      // количество символов в анонсе
      $pos = strpos(substr($news['body'],$numchar), " ");
      // Если новость длинная, то выводим троеточие...
      if(strlen($news['body'])>$numchar) $srttmpend = "...";
      else $strtmpend = "";
      // Выводим анонс
      echo "<p class=newsblock>".substr($news['body'], 0, $numchar+$pos).$srttmpend;
      echo "<br><a class=anewsblock href=news.html>more...</a></p>";
      ?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?
    }
  }
?>
<br><br>
```

Подгружаемый файл php в файл выше:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title><?php echo $titlepage; ?></title>
<?
    if (!isset($style)) {
    ?>
        <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo $style ?>">    
    <?
    }
?>
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../util/admin.css">
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="util/admin.css">
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../css">

<body leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" topmargin="0" >

<div><h1 class=z1><? echo nl2br($titlepage); ?></h1></nobr></div>
<div><p class=help><? echo $helppage ?></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .load() работает когда у тебя загружается все файлы и все скрипты, получается у тебя он ждал пока ответит файл css

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в данной строчке кода, она указывала в пустоту, из-за этого возникал конфликт в js, после ее удаления все заработало.

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="../css">
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит удалить вопрос, раз проблема была, по сути, из-за оЧепятки

Comment: Если объясните как так получалось, что скрипт отрабатывал после какого-то действия, хотя такой функции не задано, и в то же время мог не отработать, то он окончательно отпадет.